# Validate Schema is valid JSON Schema and not data

Tags: java, json, validation, schema, jsonschema

I have to provide to the client the possibility to upload his own JSON Schema.

Is there a way to validate that the JSON Schema provided by the user is a valid JSON Schema and not just data?

I am using Java with this library https://github.com/networknt/json-schema-validator

UPDATE:

I am having the following schema:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "title": "car",
  "description": "representation of car",
  "type": "object",
  "required": [
    "id",
    "make",
    "age",
    "model",
    "mileage",
    "fuel"
  ],
  "properties": {
    "id": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "make": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "model": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "age": {
      "type": "integer",
      "minimum": 0
    },
    "color": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "power_in_hp": {
      "type": "integer",
      "minimum": 0
    },
    "fuel": {
      "enum": ["gasoline", "diesel", "hybrid", "electric"]
    },
    "mileage": {
      "type": "integer",
      "minimum": 0
    }
  }
}
```

I need to know whether this is a valid JSON Schema and not JSON data.
An example for JSON data is provided here:

```
{
    "id": "1f5abf56-7210-481a-b2d5-324b6e0f6358",
    "make": "Volkswagen",
    "model": "Lupo",
    "age": 18,
    "color": "black",
    "power_in_hp": 61,
    "fuel": "diesel",
    "mileage": 401234
  }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to validate a JSON object in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32038543/how-to-validate-a-json-object-in-java)

Comment: No. I have attached an example. Hope it's clearer now.

Comment: This is a solid question, no idea why it was down-voted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you want to validate that JSON against the [JSON Schema meta schema](http://json-schema.org/specification.html#meta-schemas).

It will make sure the schema is valid as far as possible, but not that it makes sense or isn't illogical or impossible.