# How to assert that a property in body has only a few predefined values

Tags: java, testing, rest-assured, hamcrest, web-api-testing

Json body:

```
{
  "result": [
    {
      "object": {
        "type": "mattress"
      }
    },
    {
      "object": {
        "type": "pillow"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

How do I assert that type is only either pillow or a mattress (there can be more so I am looking for a generic solution) using rest-assured body and hamcrest assertions?

Example assertion:

```
response.then().assertThat().body("result", hasSize(greaterThan(0)));
```

Comment: See JSON SCHEMA that si a JSON validation format https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32038543/how-to-validate-a-json-object-in-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code would solve your problem:

```
.body("result.object.type",  everyItem(isOneOf("mattress", "pillow")));
```

Comment: is there some way to do it with list? as I said there can be more types so I have created a list and the type can be any one item of the list. This does not work for some reason: response.then().assertThat().body("result.object.type", everyItem(is(oneOf(types)))) // where types is a list of strings

Comment: I converted the list to array and it worked. Thanks. One sidenote isOneOf is marked as deprecated and is(oneOf()) should be used.

Comment: @MarijKhan Thanks for your note. I've tested with version 1.3